# Update Database without Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating the following placeholder on my front page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plComments" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And in the code behind I have put a table into it:

```
var MyComments = (from dlc in db.DocumentLinkComments
                                  where dlc.PortalID == PortalID && dlc.DocumentLinkID == FeedID && dlc.HideComments.HasValue != true
                                    orderby dlc.DateCreated descending
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        CommentID = dlc.CommentID,
                                        Name = dlc.User.UserName,
                                        EmailAddress = dlc.User.Email,
                                        Comment = dlc.Comment,
                                        DateCreated = dlc.DateCreated,
                                        Like = dlc.Users.Any(u=>u.UserID == UserID)
                                    }
                                ).Take(GrabComments).ToList();

                if (MyComments.Count() > 0)
                {

                    bool ShowLike = db.DocumentLinks.FirstOrDefault(d=> d.DocumentLinkID == FeedID).HasLikeButton;
                    foreach (var MyComment in MyComments)
                    {
                        TableRow row = new TableRow();
                        TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                        // 1st Row
                        // -------
                        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                        cell.Text = MyComment.Comment.ToString();
                        row.Cells.Add(cell);

                        cell = new TableCell();
                        if (user.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "ViewOnly"))
                        {cell.Text = " ";}
                        else
                        {
                            if (ShowLike)
                                {
                                    if (MyComment.Like)
                                    {
                                        LinkButton link = new LinkButton() { Text = " ", CssClass = "ThumbsUpSelected", ToolTip="Unlike this comment", ID = MyComment.CommentID.ToString(), CommandName="Unlike"  };
                                        link.Click += link_Click;
                                        cell.Controls.Add(link);
                                        cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        LinkButton link = new LinkButton() { Text = " ", CssClass = "ThumbsUp", ToolTip = "Like this comment", ID = MyComment.CommentID.ToString(), CommandName="Like" };
                                        link.Click += link_Click;
                                        cell.Controls.Add(link);
                                        cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                { cell.Text = " "; 
                            }
                        }


                        row.Cells.Add(cell);

                        plComments.Controls.Add(row);
```

With this function being fired when I click on the like or dislike images:

```
        private void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
        int commentID = Convert.ToInt16(link.ID);
        string action = link.CommandName;
        using (var db = new CRMSEntities())
        {
           User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == Page.User.Identity.Name);

           if (action == "Unlike") 
           {
               if (user.DocumentLinkComments1.Any(c => c.CommentID == commentID))
               {
                   user.DocumentLinkComments1.Remove(db.DocumentLinkComments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CommentID == commentID));
                   db.SaveChanges();
               }
           }
           else if (action == "Like") 
           {
               if (!user.DocumentLinkComments1.Any(c => c.CommentID == commentID))
               {
                   user.DocumentLinkComments1.Add(db.DocumentLinkComments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CommentID == commentID));
                   db.SaveChanges();
               }
            }
        }

    }
```

My problem is that this fires off the postback so the page goes back to the top

I don't want the page to move - I just want to click the button and the database in the background is then updated without any movement or postbacks

There seems to be help out there using AJAX but I can't find a way to apply it to my page

Comment: Did you try wrapping the liking stuff in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: How do I do that - do I place my placeholder in an <asp:updatepanel>

Comment: you should add it to the .aspx file. Like this: `<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="someid" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate><asp:PlaceHolder ID="plComments" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>`. And, of course, add ScriptManager, as user225676 mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, the way that will probably keep most of your code unchanged is to use the AJAX extensions and simply wrap your PlaceHolder in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You will need to add a [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.scriptmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to your page, then create an UpdatePanel and simply put your placeholder inside its ContentTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

try to put your placeholder inside of `asp:UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode = Conditional`. In this case all the link buttons will be inside the updatepanel and they will not update the page after postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go contrary to everyone that's saying UpdatePanel just so you know there's other options.

If you simply want to have the scroll position not change from a postback, set the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack` property for the page. Example:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

However, if you don't want a postback at all, read this. I really dislike UpdatePanel. It almost always causes more trouble than it's worth. If you want to prevent a postback and not use UpdatePanel, then use AJAX to make a call to your server side and perform the update there. You'll need a [Web Service (ASMX)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359) or Web API or [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation). WCF is the most flexible but steepest learning curve. Web Service is really not supposed to be used anymore, so [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is a great way to go. And on the client side, to make my calls easier, I tend to use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

The way this goes is that you'll run a JavaScript function when your Like or Dislike button is clicked. That function will call a server side method to update the database, and return a success flag. If successful, update your UI to indicate that the liking or disliking was successful.

Comment: The MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback seems to work really well with UpdatePanel - not sure why. And I added in my link_Click function some code to control what image to display. Thank you so much for all your help here ;o)